# How init pointer to data of templated ancestor

Tags: c++, templates

Just a sample code:

```
template <class T> class TempBase
{
protected:
  string m_str;
};

template <class T> class Temp: public TempBase<T>
{
public:
  void method()
  {
    string
        &s = TempBase<T>::m_str //reference works fine
        /*NOTE compile failed:
        error: ‘std::string TempBase<int>::m_str’ is protected
        error: within this context
        error: cannot convert ‘std::string TempBase<int>::* {aka std::basic_string<char> TempBase<int>::*}’ to ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’ in initialization
        */
      , *ps = &TempBase<T>::m_str 
      , *ps2 = &m_str //compile failed, obviously: ‘m_str’ was not declared in this scope
      , *ps3 = &s //this is workaround, works fine
    ;
  }
};

void f()
{
  Temp<int> t;
  t.method();
}
```

Goal: init pointer of type `std::string *` with ancestor member `TempBase<T>::m_str`.

Problem: correct syntax unknown

Comments: previous code contains 2 intentional compile errors:

1. attempt to convert member pointer to data pointer
2. templated ancestry members must be fully qualified

and 1 workaround.

Question: what is a correct syntax in this case to obtain pointer to ancestor data?

Comment: `&this->m_str` (dependent name lookup). `&TempBase<T>::m_str` tries to create a pointer-to-member, which isn't allowed here because of the access specifier, however you could use `&this->TempBase<T>::m_str` (but it's redundant)

Comment: **YES** I forget a magic word `this`. It works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `&m_str` doesn't work: [temp.dep]/3

> In the definition of a class or class template, if a base class depends on a *template-parameter*, the base class scope is not examined during unqualified name lookup [...]

However, `this->m_str` denotes a dependent name (because `this` is dependent per [temp.dep.expr]/2). In this case, dependent name lookup is used, which finds the base class member.

The problem is more obvious if we add a specialization of the template and a name outside the class scope:

```
string m_str;

template<class T> struct A { string m_str; };
template<> struct A<int> { /* no member */ };

template<class T> struct B : A
{
    void foo() { m_str = "hello"; }
};

B<int>().foo();    // clearly modifies the global `m_str`
B<double>().foo(); // modifies what?
```

If the base class scope was searched, it would not be known before the instantiation (before the template argument is known) what `m_str` refers to. Also, this could easily lead to unexpected results.

Therefore, base class scope is not searched (if the base class is dependent and if we're in a "template context").

---

The reason why `&s = TempBase<T>::m_str` works:

The *id-expression* `TempBase<T>::m_str` is using a *qualified-id*, therefore the scope of `TempBase<T>` is searched and the member `m_str` is found.

---

The reason why `&TempBase<T>::m_str` doesn't work, but `&(TempBase<T>::m_str)` does: [expr.unary.op]/3

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*. If the operand is a *qualified-id* naming a non-static member `m` of some class `C` with type `T`, the result has type “pointer to member of class `C` of type `T`” and is a prvalue designating `C::m`. Otherwise, if the type of
>   the expression is `T`, the result has type “pointer to `T`” and is a prvalue that is the address of the designated object (1.7) or a pointer to the designated function.

The paranthesized expression `(TempBase<T>::m_str)` is not a *qualified-id* and therefore `&(TempBase<T>::m_str)` doesn't form a pointer-to-member, but an ordinary pointer to the object denoted by `(TempBase<T>::m_str)`.

Comment: About &(TempBase<T>::m_str). You are clear and exhaustive, thanks. But my compiler ignores parentheses. Compiler is g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: @dyomas That must be a compiler bug, fixed, unfortunately I cannot find it currently in the bugzilla database. Tried with 4.6.4 and got the same error (it thinks it's a pointer-to-member). Same code with 4.8.1 (both using `-std=c++03`) works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that the behaviour you want is best described by the workaround

```
&s = TempBase<T>::m_str;
```

(which you provide in the question) and not by the workaround

```
&s = this->m_str;
```

which would work too in your example.

Solution: &(TempBase::m_str)

Reason: TempBase::m_str is a qualified-id, (TempBase::m_str) is not.

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class TempBase
{
protected:
  string m_str;
};

template <class T> class Temp: public TempBase<T>
{
public:
  void method()
  {
    string* ps3 = &(TempBase<T>::m_str); //this is workaround, works fine
    (*ps3) += "ciao";
    cout << *ps3 << endl;
  }
};

void f()
{
  Temp<int> t;
  t.method();
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    f();

}
```

which you can try [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/705a16eb95d13cb9)

Comment: **NO** My compiler is g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3. It behaves exactly the same in your example and in my one. And I tried to brace member before asking too...

Comment: and with visual studio 2003

Comment: visual studio 2003 gives an error (error C2248: "TempBase<T>::m_str": impossibile accedere a protected membro dichiarato nella classe "TempBase<T>") if I write &TempBase<T>::m_str

Comment: The paranthesized expression `(TempBase<T>::m_str)` is not a *qualified-id* and therefore `&(TempBase<T>::m_str)` doesn't form a pointer-to-member, but an ordinary pointer to the object denoted by `(TempBase<T>::m_str)`. Ergo: it is correct and should work.

Comment: and with visual studio 2005 (which is behaving in the exact same way as visual studio 2003 in this example)

Comment: (However, it has slightly different semantics than `this->m_str` or `m_str` in the case of a non-dependent name)

Comment: Above example compiled with g++ 4.6.3 in non-templated version (without `template` keyword and angle brackets at all)